# detecting intercept in wicket w/o calling continueToOriginalDestination()

Tags: authorization, wicket, redirect, mount

I created a `SimplePageAuthorizationStrategy` that redirects an unauthorized user to my `LoginPage.class` to authenticate / authorize and then in the `onSubmit()` I use `continueToOriginalDestination()` to forward the request to the original destination (e.g. a `mount()` or `BookmarkablePageLink`). It works correctly.

Now I would like to add an message on the page to the effect of:

*Please log in before continuing to "http://server/protected"*.

Rather than the usual *"Please log in!"* when the user gets to the login page this way.

How can I detect if the `LoginPage.class` has intercepted this request during the constructor in order to add this feedback? Calling `continueToOriginalDestination()` is not the answer, that seems to redirect right away, correct?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This information is well encapsulated and it is hard to read it. 
You can set your own flag in the session before redirecting to LoginPage and reset it after read.